# Do I need to release the Objects in NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, nsmutablearray

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cocoa Memory Management NSArray with Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411520/cocoa-memory-management-nsarray-with-objects)

I have an NSMutableArray filled with some objects.

For example:

```
...
id test = [NSObject new]; 
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray new];
[myArray addObject: test];
...
```

When more than one object need a reference to that array, I can't just use the method "– removeAllObjects".
So I only use the release of the array in my "- dealloc" method of my own classes.

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [myArray release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

So is my object with the name "test" leaked and therefore I do need to do more?

I couldn't find the answer in the documentation, the is no point for the "dealloc" or "release" method for NSMutableArray. And in the NSObject reference they don't describe the NSMutableArray. 
Could be it is anywhere in the "Memory Management Programming Guide" (hope so).

Comment: Possible duplicates:  [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822768/) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795615/) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411520/) [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241283/) [5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570411/) [6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668919/) [...](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nsarray+leak)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only release what you own, whether through alloc, new, retain, or copy.

You own test after you do

```
id test = [NSObject new];
```

so you are responsible for releasing it, whether you add it to an array or not.

If you do

```
id test = [[NSObject new] autorelease]; // or any autoreleased convenience methods
```

you've already given up ownership of test, so you shouldn't be releasing it, even if you put it in an array or some other form of collection. The collection will take ownership.

You only have to release the things you own.

Answer (score 5):

Containers will retain their contained objects and release them when the container is destroyed or objects are removed from them. You should release objects after they are added to the container (since they are retained by container, so you no longer need to retain them).

Comment: By which we mean: you should release objects after they are added to the container, **if you own them**. So, in the example provided (with `+new`), you'll have to release the object after adding it to the container. However, if you transferred ownership of the object to an autorelease pool (by sending `-autorelease` to the object), you mustn't release it.